# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier loads old cell (with fields that no longer exists)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uistoryboard

I am trying to remove fields from a custom UITableViewCell (MyTableViewCell), but when I run `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` and look at the debug console, it shows me the fields that I have deleted!

Here is the debug console. You can see its of type `MyTableViewCell`
[image]

But here is the MyTableViewCell class. It doesn't have fields `titleLabel`, `gradientTitleBackground`, or `myImageView`. (because I have deleted them)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RouteImageView.h"

@interface MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet RouteImageView *routeImageView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *totalMilesLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *progressLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIProgressView *progressView;

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *medalPlaceholder;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *medal;

@end
```

The next two shots show my storyboard configuration. You can see that I have a tableview cell with reuse ID: "walk_item", and that this cell is mapped to the class MyTableViewCell...

[image]
[image]

And the line where I load the cell (and where I read the debug console) is here:

```
MyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"walk_item"];
```

So why isn't the cell being properly updated? This is a problem because when I try to add new fields and connect them to IABOutlet's, the program crashes with EXEC_BAD_ACCESS! Something is not connecting properly between storyboard and my custom UITableViewCell class. Any suggestions on ideas how to debug this are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try a clean build? Sounds like it uses a different version of your code at runtime.

Comment: Yes, I just realized this was my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to do a clean build.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath` instead of simple `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. I also have strange issues with table, when using that function

```
MyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"walk_item" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```